# How to let VSCode/Typescript to do auto complete on imported classes?

Tags: typescript, class, visual-studio-code, import, export

Let's say I have a file, `class.ts`

```
//I tried implementing interface, but it won't help, with or without the interface
interface FooInterface {
    bar: Function
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {

    bar() {
        console.log('Hello world!');
    }

}

export = new Foo();
```

From my other file, `index.js`, I am expecting VS Code to be able to read what's inside the class `Foo` and autocompletes, but it doesn't.

```
const Foo = require('./class');

///Expecting the .bar() suggestion after typing Foo., but it didn't happen
Foo.bar();
```

Am I missing something? What should I do so that VS Code can recognize what methods/properties are available within the class? A lot of third party libraries are able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern looks a little strange to me so I created a sandbox for you,

Hope it will help

here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-fog-hngl5?file=/src/index.js:0-72

I'll also paste the code here in case you wanted to see the differences

```
interface FooInterface {
  bar: () => void
}

export default class Foo implements FooInterface {

  bar() {
      console.log('Hello world!');
  }

}
```

and here is how you import it:

```
import Foo from './class';

const FooInstance = new Foo();
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much. Can you please explain to me the difference between `import { Foo } from './class'` and `import Foo from `./class`? The former didn't work, and by changing it to the latter, it worked.

Comment: if you export a module by ```default``` keyword such as ```export default Foo``` you would import it like this: ```import Foo from './class'```

 and if you just use export without default keyword like this: ```export Foo``` you need to import it like this ```import { Foo } from './class'```
@user3622260

read this : https://javascript.info/import-export